# syslog-ng viewer that can display many log files of different IDS

Tags: security, syslog

I have three Intrusion detection systems installed (snort, modsecurity,ossec) and I want to visualize the generated log files of these IDS.

Is there a Graphical User Interface that can display the log files?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

ELSA has parsers for many IDS, firewall etc. log messages and can create nice visualizations: https://github.com/mcholste/elsa

Actually there is also an Ubuntu based security distro which has all of these integrated: https://security-onion-solutions.github.io/security-onion/